# Selenium with Serenity Explicit Wait Continues To Execute After True Condition Is Returned

Tags: java, selenium, wait, serenity-bdd

Selenium with Serenity Explicit Wait Continues To Execute After True Condition Is Returned

- So, what I'm Trying to do is wait for busy Overlay to be displayed
- Element appears in DOM only briefly about 3 seconds and then disappears from DOM
- Condition gets met as `System.out.println("Busy Overlay Displayed");` gets printed
- Which means `True` gets returned
- But, explicit wait continues to execute as `System.out.println("Size Appear = " + driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'tg-loading')]")).size());` continues to execute afterwards and print size = 0
- Why is explicit wait continues to execute after `True` condition is met ?

  ```
  public void waitForBusyOverlayDisplayed(WebDriver driver) {

      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);       
      wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {

          @Override
          public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {

              System.out.println("Size Appear = " + driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'tg-loading')]")).size());
              if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'tg-loading')]")).size() == 1){


                  System.out.println("Busy Overlay Displayed");
                  return Boolean.TRUE;                                
              }                   

              return false;        
          }       
      }); 

  }
  ```

Comment: Can you post the output of the test so we can see the messages being printed? Can you also show the code that calls this method?

Comment: CommonSteps.WaitForBusyOverlayDisplayed() is the calling code and output is : size 0, size 1 , overlay is displayed, 0, 0, 0, 0 It’s continues loop thereafter

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think ExpectedCondition is an interface.  (which is a sort of type... and then you type-cast it to bool... and I don't know what's going to happen there, but maybe it's always returning false on the creation of the instance) Maybe create a class which implements the interface instead.